# Detect Low Light Condition and FaceRotation Angle in Degrees in Real-Time FaceDetection IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, opencv, face-detection

I am writing an iOS app that will do **real-time face-detection** using iPhone's Front camera.

In it, I need to check whether the lighting is proper or not. Like checking for "low light condition" or is left half light is more than right half light or vice versa.

I am checking both OpenCV on iOS and the iOS default face-detction using `CIDetector` for one week but I am unable to find the solution.

Any Ideas or samples will be helpful.

In the same project iam using CIFaceFeature+FaceRotation to detect the face rotation angle its returning -1 to +1 values, but i need to show the values in 0 to 180 degrees (like user face is tilted 30 degrees)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check below link it might not actually solve your problem but yes it can give you an idea about luminosity of ios camera image for the starter:

https://www.transpire.com/insights/blog/obtaining-luminosity-ios-camera/

Comment: i have small doubt in the same project iam using CIFaceFeature+FaceRotation to detect the face rotation angle its returning -1 to +1 values, but i need to show the values in 0 to 180 degrees (like user face is tilted 30 degrees)

Answer (score 0):

generally, checking for "low light condition" could use statistic methods like:

[thanks spider1983](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera)

or histogram things.

for "left half light is more than right half light or vice versa. ", if you are meaning the left half of the face.
 I don't think ios face detection api helps. you can't get where is exactly the left face, the eyes, the nose... with face detection only.

face detection gives you, "OK, here is a face, roughly this size"

check these methods for more detail face modelling.
[asm1](http://ice.dlut.edu.cn/lu/ASM.html) [asm2](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/)

also, check this interesting latest challenge: [ICCV2013](http://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/300-W/)